R visNetwork arrow type
The below code is meant to yield the following network graph:
.
library(visNetwork)
library(magrittr)

nodes <- data.frame(id=c("a","b","c","d"), label=c("a","b","c","d"))
edges <- data.frame(
  from = c("a","a","a"),
  to = c("b","c","d"),
  arrows.from.type = c(NA,"circle","circle"),
  arrows.to.type = c("arrow","circle",NA)
)

visNetwork(nodes, edges)

This, however, is the graph I get:
.
The edges should have arrows and circles, but they are entirely blank. The above code has been shown to work (e.g., here), but I cannot get it to produce the intended graph, with the arrows and circles at the beginning and end points of the specified edges. I am using R version 4.4.1. Any ideas what I'm missing? Thanks!

Something to try is setting arrows.to.enabled = c(T, T, F) and arrows.from.enabled = c(F, T, T) inside of your edges dataframe. Something I came across looking at this documentation.

This question is similar to: R visNetwork: adding edge types and arrow placement. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please do not repost the same question twice. Sometimes it can take time for users to answer your questions. Thanks.
